# What do you call someone whose rights have been taken away from them?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if someone took my right/freedom of speech, by forcing punishments or such.

What do I become? Is there one word to describe this situation (where rights are taken away)?

Comment: You may want to re-word this question, "What do you call someone whose rights have been taken away from them?"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Disenfranchised* is used in the sense of denied the right to vote, but can be extended to other rights as well:

> **disenfranchise** (also *disfranchise*)
>   *verb* [ with obj. ]
>   deprive (someone) of the right to vote: *the law disenfranchised some 3,000 voters on the basis of a residence qualification*.
>   • (as adj. disenfranchised) deprived of power; marginalized: *a hard core of kids who are disenfranchised and don't feel connected to the school*.
>   • deprive (someone) of a right or privilege: *a measure that would disenfranchise people from access to legal advice.*
>   <sub>NOAD</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As though you were *[stripped](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strip)* of your right?

> c : to divest of honors, privileges, or functions

Answer (score 1):

Abjected. Made abject.

"Severely unequal societies require frequent abjection to stifle spontaneous forms of revolt."

Answer (score 0):

*Suppressed* or *oppressed* might work.

Comment: there's a collection of words somewhere out there in this world which says: "suppressed, oppressed and depressed!". Not sure what it means!!

Answer (score 0):

A person who has had their rights *unfairly* removed is a *victim*.